# How to access virtual property from model class

Tags: c#

I have below model class in my project. I need to access from that virtual property `Posts` through `Blog` class. Please let me know any solution

```
public class Blog {  
    public int BlogId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Url { get; set; }  
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: How about: `Blog b = GetBlog(); b.Posts` ?

Comment: is it possible? because its virtual property

Comment: I suggest you learn the language before learning entity framework (that's most likely your case) or whatever library you use with your model.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to access Blog Parent from Post, so if we are talking about Entity Framework, you should create a Navigation Property in Post Model.

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(Blog))]
public int BlogId { get; set; }
public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
```

EF will create the access to Blog Parent from Post, and you can access to Blog using the property.

```
Blog Parent = Post.Blog;
```